# What is the optimal way to return a private value from inside a class?

Tags: c#, class, optimization, private, public

I'm attempting to optimize my code for maximum readability and for that I need my code to be in-line through and through. I will present two snippets of code as an example. In my eyes the below one is more easier for the eyes. These snippets (one of them) would be stored in a class and setting *width* should only be possible inside the class while getting *Width* should always be possible.

**A:**

```
private int width;
public int Width
{
    get { return width; }
    private set { }
}
```

**B:**

```
private int width;
public int Width()
{
    return width;
}
```

As far as I am concerned these two ways of achieving the same end result are identical. Because I would like to be thoroughly in-line in all my classes I wouldn't want to use both ways mixed together. The B-approach seems cleaner in my eyes.

**Are there any downsides/upsides to either approach. Should one approach be favored over the other? Are A and B approaches really completely identical?**

Comment: `public int Width { get; private set; }`

Comment: Imo it wouldn't make sense to call a method (which would be expected to execute some functionality) to get or set a value, in the same way that it wouldn't be expected that extensive functionality is executed when getting a value from a property. I think your **B** option is cleaner but this may simply be down to the choice and style of the coder in question.

Comment: @zerkms Can you please post that comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

In general best practice says that when doing object oriented programming, you should use methods to perform actions, which may or might affect the state of the object (other than a single attribute value), and you should use properties (setters and getters) to fetch or set object attributes.

Method names should therefore (in general) describe what the method does (the syntax should be like a Verb) whereas Property names should be nouns (referencing some attribute of the object)

Under the surface, of course, the .Net compiler turns all property getters and setters into methods, (in the IL code there is no such thing as a property) but the principal articulated above allows you to see at a glance whether an expression is "Doing" something, or simply accessing an attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why everything has to be thoroughly in-line, or why that makes anything more readable.

This this would seem to be the most concise implementation in any case.

```
public int Width 
{ 
    get; 
    private set; 
}
```

Remove the white space if you really must but I'm not sure if that's really an improvement.

`public int Width { get; private set; }`

The [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182181.aspx) offers some guidance in this situation:

> In most cases, properties represent data and methods perform actions.
>   Properties are accessed like fields, which makes them easier to use. A
>   method is a good candidate to become a property if one of these
>   conditions is present:
>
> - Takes no arguments and returns the state information of an object.
> - Accepts a single argument to set some part of the state of an object.
>
> Properties should behave as if they are fields; if the method cannot,
>   it should not be changed to a property. Methods are better than
>   properties in the following situations:
>
> - The method performs a time-consuming operation. The method is    perceivably slower than the time that is required to set or get the
>     value of a field.
> - The method performs a conversion. Accessing a field does not return a    converted version of the data that it stores.
> - The Get method has an observable side effect. Retrieving the value of    a field does not produce any side effects.
> - The order of execution is important. Setting the value of a field    does not rely on the occurrence of other operations.
> - Calling the method two times in succession creates different results.
> - The method is static but returns an object that can be changed by the    caller.
> - Retrieving the value of a field does not allow the caller    to change the data that is stored by the field.
> - The method returns an array.